# I can't get Object Index to give me a clean Luma Matte. Please Help!

Tags: render-passes, antialiasing, id-mask

[image]

Why is it that I can't get a clean looking Luma Matte from either Object Index or Material Index Pass. As you can see in the example I provided, I do have anti-aliasing checked in the ID Mask. What is it that I'm doing wrong here? Or does it even work? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are only rendering at 50% resolution. At 100% resolution it will look sharper.

1920 px x 1080 px at 100% is probably fine for video.

If it's for a still image go crazy and try something like 6000 px x 4000 px at 100%.

[image]

Comment: This was auto flagged as low quality because of length and content, you might want to add a few details on how to change the resolution etc

Comment: I see this is flagged as a duplicate with a link to a question that has never been acknowledged as answered and relates to another issue with IDmasks. Not exactly helpful.